# Synctex with large equations?

Tags: equations, amsmath, forward-inverse-search

I am often working with large equations inside `align` environment, that span upwards of four lines, often resulting in upwards of 500 characters spread across upwards of 20 lines. If anything needs to be changed (typos, changes in notation, ...), finding the correct position is quite tedious, as synctex doesn't seem to allow navigating inside the equations - it will only point to the `\end{align}` line.

Is there any method of typesetting aligned, numbered equations, that does NOT break synctex?

Comment: I would comment all independent lines (from the point I am sure that the code works) and then un-comment one by one. The good with `align` is that it contains independent parts (lines).

Comment: @koleygr I changed the question text to make it clear, that I don't mean compilation errors, but content errors such as typos (e.g. $x_{ij}$ vs $x_{ji}$).

Comment: Ok... I didn't understand before... But it was my mistake... It was clear enough... But I can't help you

Comment: If you have 20 source lines and think the fault is about line 5 you could add to the end of lines 4 5 6 the following %\end{align*}\begin{align*} then to split in parts to aid synctex just remove the %comment symbols, yes its a very crude workaround but it may help to split the output down to be more manageable.

Comment: @KJO While workable, the added overhead of adding and removing these additional split lines would pretty much cancel the productivity gained from more precise Syntex. Though [currently I'd already be glad to find the correct align environment](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/342) without workarounds.

Comment: You could raise an issue on GitHub as this is not just confined to Align but is a good example case (there are others) Also some editors with integrated viewers can improve their precision by using "hinting" so they look a few characters each side of the "word" indicated and can jump to the corresponding source If I remember correctly mac users are served best.